# C#/mySQL Data Retrieval Problems over Network

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a mySQL database running on a server on the local network.

If I make a normal `SELECT` statement, I  get 6000 results. The execution time in the mySQL query browser is `0.35s`, but the data is received and shown in query browser after `9s`.

I have the same problem if I try to access the data through the .NET application. The query itself is fast, but the showing it in the application is slow.

Does anyone have any idea as to what would cause this?

Comment: It would help us if you'd show us the code you're using to fetch the data, as well as things like the connection string, the driver you're using etc.

Comment: Looks like you and I collided on edits, Chris.

Comment: why... if i say it happened also in the query browser it has to be a problemm with mysql not with my connection string etc...

Comment: Yes, mySQL must have a bug in it.

Answer (score 1):

If the records are vast it could purely be down to the time it takes for the data to be transmitted across the network. You don't give much detail though so it's hard to say.

Comment: if i do it with 6000 values or 3 it is the same 8 seconds... i have no idea - thats why i ask... i added skip-name-resolve to my my.cnf file, but this changed nothing

Answer (score 1):

Set up a profiler, to check where the time is going to. I would also set up an integration test that only does direct call to the c# method that gets the results.

Ps. I re-read the question, it really looks the usual case of it taking a long time to go over the network. I would double check if it really gets the same behavior with a few records.